Circular Inversion such that image of two circles is formed by two concentric ones

I'm interested in finding an inversion such that the image of the two circles $C_1,C_2$ is formed by two concentric circles. If $P$ was the center of the inversion, I'd have that the image of $C$ is the line passing through the points of intersection between the circle of inversion and itself; but I'm not sure about justifying how inverted $C_1,C_2$ would have the same center; any suggestions?
